# Any one Place Our Chat Widget in their website from<iframe> script , I want this widget down when our website is not responding or down

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

We make Chat Widget from iframe /iframe tags

Any one Place Our " Chat Widget " in their website from script but the problem is when our main website is down it gives error in client website where widget is placed

I want this "Chat widget" down when our website is not responding or down

How can I detect this from iframe events that my main website is down or not ?

Thanks

Comment: Whats your question, what do you want to achieve. Please be clear in what you are looking for.

Comment: repeating the entire title of your question AS the question is not going to get your gibberish answered any faster.

Comment: Seriously, what is the question here?

Comment: So you want your website to respond to requests while it is down or geo-blocked??

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist : Yes Bro ,

Comment: So your question is: how can I get my web server to respond to requests while it is not responding to requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you are giving an iframe code for your users to copy-paste in their websites. And when your site goes down, the iframe starts showing an error message.

What you want is to change the way your iframe is inserted on your clients' websites. Instead of giving the iframe code, you should give them a script that checks your site for availability (by AJAX request or some other way), and then generates an iframe if the site is up.

Comment: Please, please read up on non-blocking JavaScript techniques if you are going to do this, or you will have loads of angry clients wondering why _their_ websites will not load because (unbeknownst to them) your script is idling for 30 seconds wondering why your website (which is down) won't talk to it.